# Stop Current Thread Issue

Tags: android, multithreading

My Problem is I am Running one Method into Thread and after 30 Seconds I will display alertdialog and click on alertdialog's ok button i will stop current thread but problem is thread is not stop, following is my Code and sorry for bad english comunication

```
public class CountDownTimerActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

    Thread t;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myTimer.start();
        mDeclaration();
        myTimer.cancel();
    }

    private CountDownTimer myTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        // This will give you 30 sec timer with each tick at 1 second

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            t.interrupt();
            //t.stop();
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    CountDownTimerActivity.this);
            alert.setMessage("Loading...");
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
            alert.show();
        }
    };

    public void mDeclaration() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            System.out.println("Printing OK" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737420/how-to-stop-or-destroy-a-running-thread/9737664#9737664)...instead you can put a flag in run method.. and check whether to run or not to run the code in thread.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
public class CountDownTimerActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

Thread t;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();

}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myTimer.start();
    mDeclaration();
    myTimer.cancel();
}

private CountDownTimer myTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
    // This will give you 30 sec timer with each tick at 1 second

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    public void onFinish() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                CountDownTimerActivity.this);
        alert.setMessage("Loading...");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //  t.interrupt();
        t.stop();
                    }
                });
        alert.show();
    }
};

public void mDeclaration() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        System.out.println("Printing OK" + i);
    }
}
```

}