# gradle test dependencies not loaded after JDK upgrade NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala, gradle, scope, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

Since yesterday I get a weird class path error - after upgrading the JDK:

```
*NoClassDefFoundError*: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/session/SessionState when creating Hive client using classpath: file:/Users/geoheil/project/build/classes/java/test, file:/Users/geoheil/project/build/classes/scala/test/
    Please make sure that jars for your version of hive and hadoop are included in the paths passed to spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.
```

However, in IntelliJ it works just fine.
See the configuration for details:

```
dependencies {


        compileOnly deps.sparkCore
        compileOnly deps.sparkSql
        compileOnly deps.sparkHive
        compileOnly deps.sparkMllib
        compileOnly deps.scalaLib

        testImplementation deps.scalaT
        testRuntime deps.pgdown
        testImplementation deps.scalaC
        testImplementation deps.sparkTestingB

    }

    configurations {
        testCompile.extendsFrom compileOnly
    }
```

Detailed configuration can be found at https://github.com/geoHeil/classpath-gradle-test-failures/blob/master/build.gradle simply:

- git clone
- gradle test

java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_192"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning during your project's compilation step hints that Java 9+ is used. For details about the new module system see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50259167/472362).

With Java 8 set, your demo project runs just fine, whereas Java 10 fails with the error you've described. I'd expect the same error for any JDK 9+ version.

Oracle JDK 8 (1.8.0_181):

```
$ gradle clean test --console=plain -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
> Task :clean
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileScala NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE

> Task :compileTestScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.

> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses

> Task :test
Discovery starting.
Discovery completed in 117 milliseconds.
Run starting. Expected test count is: 2
18/10/19 13:24:28 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/10/19 13:24:30 WARN SparkContext: Using an existing SparkContext; some configuration may not take effect.
Test2:
foo2
18/10/19 13:24:37 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
18/10/19 13:24:37 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
18/10/19 13:24:37 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
root
 |-- value: integer (nullable = false)

+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
+-----+

- should test fine (7 seconds, 859 milliseconds)
hello
Test1:
foo
- should test fine (1 millisecond)
Run completed in 10 seconds, 497 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 2
Suites: completed 3, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
All tests passed.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 18s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

JDK 10 (10.0.2):

```
$ gradle clean test --console=plain -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
...
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.parboiled.transform.AsmUtils (file:/Users/bountin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.parboiled/parboiled-java/1.1.7/2298c64ce8ee8e2fb37e97e16d7be52f0c7cf61f/parboiled-java-1.1.7.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.parboiled.transform.AsmUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
...
- should test fine *** FAILED *** (2 seconds, 210 milliseconds)
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1075)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:142)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:141)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:141)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:171)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:62)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataset(SparkSession.scala:471)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataset(SQLContext.scala:377)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/session/SessionState when creating Hive client using classpath: file:/Users/bountin/classpath-gradle-test-failures/build/classes/java/test, file:/Users/bountin/classpath-gradle-test-failures/build/classes/scala/test/
Please make sure that jars for your version of hive and hadoop are included in the paths passed to spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.
...
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. `java -version java version "1.8.0_192"` returns 8 and jenny as well. I will need to figure out where it is picking up the wrong java home.

Comment: `jenv enable-plugin export` solves the second part (https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv/issues/44).