# llegal reflective access at HtmlPipelineContext constructor of itext 5

Tags: java, reflection, itext, pdf-generation

context: jdk11, springboot, itextpdf 5.5.13.3, ubuntu, eclipse

during: `new HtmlPipelineContext(null);` throughout `new CssAppliersImpl(new XMLWorkerFontProvider());` and last `CssAppliersImpl(){// map builder inside }` appears

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.itextpdf.text.io.ByteBufferRandomAccessSource$1 (file:/home/awieclawski/.m2/repository/com/itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.13.3/itextpdf-5.5.13.3.jar) to method java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.cleaner()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.itextpdf.text.io.ByteBufferRandomAccessSource$1
```

question: how to avoid it?

PS.
Before `HtmlPipelineContext` instance is established:

```
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);
 //     cssFile is returned from XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(getCssStream(path));
    }
```

and at the debug of `new HtmlPipelineContext(null);` is signalized: `com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred invoking method.`

solution:

there is problematic line (503) in `FontFactoryImp` where static method `BaseFont.enumerateTTCNames(path);` is called. To avoid this in `XMLWorkerFontProvider` constructor should be used `XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS` as parameter value.

```
XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS); `
```

it's quite enough - problem disappeared :)

Comment: itext5 is end of life. Perhaps this answers your question? [Itext Java 11: Illegal reflective access by com.itextpdf.io.source.ByteBufferRandomAccessSource$1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301158/itext-java-11-illegal-reflective-access-by-com-itextpdf-io-source-bytebufferran)

Comment: thx, but solution is found :)