# Illegal reflective access in zookeer's kerberosUtil

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, java-11

I am using kafka 2.11-2.1.0 with Java 11 and when am running kafka-acl script to maange ACLs, I am getting below warning. Is there a way to resolve this?

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.KerberosUtil (file://apache/kafka/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/libs/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is an illegal reflective access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access)

Comment: Is there an issue in the zookeeper issue tracker for this?