# Illegal reflective access by Metro jar

Tags: java, web-services, module, java-metro-framework

I have an illegal reflective access operation caused by one of the metro jars that I use:

```
jvm 1    | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
jvm 1    | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1 (file:/C:/myapp/webservices-rt.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
jvm 1    | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1
jvm 1    | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
jvm 1    | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

- OpenJDK version: Adopt OpenJDK 11.0.4+11
- Metro version: metro-standalone-2.3.1

I've read about what an illegal reflective access is here:
[what is an illegal reflective access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access)

Do I need to use a particular module? How? I did not find any in the metro zip file.

It's not clear to me how to fix this.

Comment: There's an issue to track it here: https://github.com/javaee/jaxbv2/issues/1197 and it seems to be fixed in JAXB 2.4.0.

Comment: Link contains a typo, must be: https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/1197

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "An illegal reflective access operation has occurred" is a Java 9 feature.
Is "metro-standalone-2.3.1" Java 9+ compatible?

Comment: Good question. I downloaded it from: https://javaee.github.io/metro/ and also found this link: https://javaee.groups.io/g/metro/topic/java_11_compatibility_check/25154198?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,25154198