# Illegal Reflective access error in Processing 3 (JDK11)

Tags: java, runtime-error, processing, java-11, java-module

I've gotten this set of errors:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.jogamp.common.os.NativeLibrary$3 (file:/C:/Users/Who/processing-3.5.3/processing-3.5.3/core/library/gluegen-rt.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.jogamp.common.os.NativeLibrary$3

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Whenever I try to run a sketch. I'm working in IntelliJ, and should have all the necessary jars imported. I'm calling the `PApplet.main()` method in my main, and I've got the size set in settings(). I've tried using multiple versions of processing. The code compiles. Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is an illegal reflective access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access)

Comment: I know this is 7 months old, but for future users, try linking to the processing 4.0a core instead. I have this problem and like micycle said, you have to live with it until processing devs fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue (albeit a warning and not an error) with the JOGL/JogAmp library, upon which Processing's `P2D` and `P3D` modes are built.

The warning is being thrown by this library -- not Processing. There's nothing that you can do -- as a Processing user -- to fix it.