# Illegal reflective access operation when creating IntelliJ plugin action

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

I am trying to follow the instructions on [this page](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/action_system/working_with_custom_actions.html) for creating actions in an IntelliJ plugin. I have copied the code exactly as written, however the code does not work when run. When I click run code, IntelliJ opens in a new window. According to the above page, the plugin should work in that window. However, the plugin, which is supposed to add an item to the *tools* menu, does not work. The additional item does not appear in the menu. Additionally, I get this (possibly unrelated) warning message when I run the code.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil to field java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.runnable
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-10-22 17:40:24,829 [   6980]   WARN - tellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor - issue detected: bundled.jre.version.message 
2020-10-22 17:40:27,369 [   9520]   WARN - ion.impl.NotificationCollector - Notification group 'Heap Dump Analysis' is already registered in whitelist 
2020-10-22 17:40:27,369 [   9520]   WARN - ion.impl.NotificationCollector - Notification group 'Low Memory' is already registered in whitelist 
2020-10-22 17:40:28,602 [  10753]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=org.jetbrains.android.compose.AndroidComposeAutoDocumentation) 
2020-10-22 17:40:29,801 [  11952]   WARN - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Activities registered via registerPostStartupActivity must be dumb-aware: org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.configuration.ui.KotlinConfigurationCheckerComponent$projectOpened$1@133a2dbe 
2020-10-22 17:40:35,401 [  17552]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2020-10-22 17:40:51,973 [  34124]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.configuration.utils.ScriptClassRootsStorage
```

I don't know what this warning message is or how to fix it. I am including my source code in the event that I have copied something incorrectly from the instruction page linked above.

**PopupDialogAction.java**

```java
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.CommonDataKeys;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.openapi.ui.Messages;
import com.intellij.pom.Navigatable;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class PopupDialogAction extends AnAction {

    @Override
    public void update(AnActionEvent e) {
        // Set the availability based on whether a project is open
        Project project = e.getProject();
        e.getPresentation().setEnabledAndVisible(project != null);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(@NotNull AnActionEvent event) {
        // Using the event, create and show a dialog
        Project currentProject = event.getProject();
        StringBuffer dlgMsg = new StringBuffer(event.getPresentation().getText() + " Selected!");
        String dlgTitle = event.getPresentation().getDescription();
        // If an element is selected in the editor, add info about it.
        Navigatable nav = event.getData(CommonDataKeys.NAVIGATABLE);
        if (nav != null) {
            dlgMsg.append(String.format("\nSelected Element: %s", nav.toString()));
        }
        Messages.showMessageDialog(currentProject, dlgMsg.toString(), dlgTitle, Messages.getInformationIcon());
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'm not really sure how to fix this. Is the issue caused by that fact that I am using the default package?

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210683.

Comment: "Is the issue caused by that fact that I am using the default package?" - No, I don't think so.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Being that the messages were warnings rather than errors, do they explain why the plugin didn't work at all?

Comment: `"do they explain why the plugin didn't work at all"` - Unlikely.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Then the Illegal reflective access isn't the problem here. There has to be something wrong with the code. What else should I post in the question? I'm trying to narrow down what the issue is, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: You haven't described what the problem is aside from listing warnings and saying `"however the code does not work when run"`.  What is it that does not work?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown The plugin is supposed to add an item to the *tools* menu, but the item does not appear. The plugin is simply not running in the IntelliJ window that opens when I run it.