# What are these illegal access warning while running Kotlin and how to stop them?

Tags: java, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and while running any script, the terminal throws these warnings.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

What are these and how do I hide them?
I am using `Kotlin version 1.4.21-release-351 (JRE 15.0.1+9-18)` if that helps

Comment: The warning is related to the _Java Platform Module System_ added in Java 9. See this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access

Answer (score 1):

Hit this issue also, open issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43520

https://github.com/yschimke/okurl-scripts/issues/3

For now, the best option is to set JAVA_HOME to 1.8 instead of 9+.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yschimke/okurl-scripts/master/commands/tube-status.main.kts

```
$  ./tube-status.main.kts
Bakerloo    Good Service
Central Good Service
Circle  Minor Delays
District    Part Closure
Hammersmith & City  Minor Delays
Jubilee Good Service
Metropolitan    Minor Delays
Northern    Good Service
Piccadilly  Part Closure
Victoria    Good Service
Waterloo & City Planned Closure
```