# Warning on Illegal reflective access by com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil

Tags: java, reflection, java-11, jackson-databind, fasterxml

I am getting the below warning intermittently while running my java application,

```
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil 
(file:/usr/app/my_app.jar) to field java.lang.Throwable.cause
```

I think the below line may have connection with this,

```
private final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
AuthInfo authInfo = mapper.readValue(userInfo, AuthInfo.class);
```

However I am unable to reproduce this issue in my local even if I try with the same input that production has. I have used --add-opens to ignore these warnings, its working but I want to know why this is happening and how to fix that reflection access warnings.

Tried to use `–-illegal-access=debug` to get the stack trace but I am getting
Used:

```
java –-illegal-access=debug -jar my_application.jar
```

Getting error like,

```
Error: Could not find or load main class –-illegal-access=debug
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: –-illegal-access=debug
```

I am using Java 11.0.2

Edit:
I am also getting the below warning,

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.amazonaws.util.XpathUtils (file:/usr/app/m1x-publish.jar) to method com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathContext.getDTMManager()
```

Comment: See: [What is an illegal reflective access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access)

Comment: Thanks @Jesper . By using --add-opens I am able to avoid the com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil warning. But I am still getting warnings from amazon sdk as I have mentioned in the edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an illegal reflective access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access)

Comment: Yes, this helped me to ignore these errors. But not fixed it yet.