# Spark submit: these logs are generated without level

Tags: apache-spark, logging, log4j

I'm running Spark on Kubernetes, the logs of the spark app are sent to Datadog, are logs are okay and sent correctly except for the first 4 lines directly after spark-submit:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.2.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Since these lines don't have a level attribute attached to them, they are interpreted by Datadog as an Error, which is a bit annoying:

The rest of the logs are sent by Log4j with the level attached to the massage, something like this:

```
{
  endOfBatch: false
  instant: {
    epochMillisecond: 1686055630113.133
    epochSecond: 1686055630
    nanoOfSecond: 113133000
  }
  level: INFO
  loggerFqcn: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger
  loggerName: com.package.Main
  thread: main
  threadId: 1
  threadPriority: 5
}
```

So, how to declare the 4 first lines with Info level in the logs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an illegal reflective access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access)

Comment: These messages are not logged, they are printed by the JVM directly to `System.err`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is because you are using Spark 3.x with Java 11, 2 possible "easy" solutions:

1. Downgrade Java version from 11 to 8.
2. Upgrade Spark version to 3.3+