# Get declared fields of java.lang.reflect.Fields in jdk12

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, java-12

In java8 it was possible to access fields of class java.lang.reflect.Fields using e.g.

```
Field.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

In java12 (starting with java9 ?) this returns only a empty array. This doesn't change even with

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
```

set.

Any ideas how to achieve this? 
(Appart from the fact that this might be a bad idea, i want to be able to change a "static final" field in my code during junit testing via reflection. This has been possible with java8 by changing the "modifiers"

```
Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
modifiersField.setInt(myfield, myfield.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
```

)

Comment: I suggest taking a step back and overthinking your whole setup. Why do you want to mutate a `static` field in the first place?

Comment: @Lino This is because i need to replace a logger by a "testable" Logger implementation. I am quite sure that there are a other approaches to solve this, but i want to understand what has changed, why and where it might be documented...

Comment: IMO you should not test a logger. But the real question is still valid.

Comment: This seems to be the change: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210496 Came in JDK 12

Comment: You can still modify final fields via `sun.misc.Unsafe`, but as the name implies, it may or not break everything.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## Why It No Longer Works

The reason this no longer works in Java 12 is due to [JDK-8210522](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210522). This CSR says:

> ### Summary
>
> Core reflection has a filtering mechanism to hide security and integrity sensitive fields and methods from Class getXXXField(s) and getXXXMethod(s). The filtering mechanism has been used for several releases to hide security sensitive fields such as System.security and Class.classLoader.
>
> This CSR proposes to extend the filters to hide fields from a number of highly security sensitive classes in java.lang.reflect and java.lang.invoke.
>
> ### Problem
>
> Many of classes in java.lang.reflect and java.lang.invoke packages have private fields that, if accessed directly, will compromise the runtime or crash the VM. Ideally all non-public/non-protected fields of classes in java.base would be filtered by core reflection and not be readable/writable via the Unsafe API but we are no where near this at this time. In the mean-time the filtering mechanism is used as a band aid.
>
> ### Solution
>
> Extend the filter to all fields in the following classes:
>
> ```
> java.lang.ClassLoader
> java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor
> java.lang.reflect.Field
> java.lang.reflect.Method
> ```
>
> and the private fields in java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup that are used for the lookup class and access mode.
>
> ### Specification
>
> There are no specification changes, this is filtering of non-public/non-protected fields that nothing outside of java.base should rely on. None of the classes are serializable.

Basically, they filter out the fields of `java.lang.reflect.Field` so you can't abuse them—as you're currently trying to do. You should find another way to do what you need; the [answer by Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56042394/6395627) appears to provide at least one option.

---

## Proper Fix

The proper way to drop a `final` modifier is to [instrument](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) the running program, and have your agent redefine the class. If you do this when the class is first loaded, it's no different than having modified the class file before the JVM was even started. In other words, it's like the `final` modifier was never present.

---

## Workaround

**Obligatory Warning:** The developers of Java obviously don't want you to be able to change a final field into a non-final field without actually changing the class file (e.g., by recompiling the source code, instrumentation, etc.). Use any hack at your own risk; it may have unintended side-effects, work only some times, and/or stop working in a future release.

### Use `java.lang.invoke`

The following uses the `java.lang.invoke` package. For whatever reason, the same restrictions applied to the Reflection API are not applied to the Invoke API (at least up to and including Java 17; continue reading for more information).

The example modifies the `EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA` final field of the `ArrayList` class. This field normally contains an empty array that's shared between all `ArrayList` instances when initialized with a capacity of `0`. The below sets the field to `{"Hello", "World!"}`, and as you can see by running the program, this results in the list instance containing elements that were never added to it.

#### Java 12 - 17

I tested this on Java 16.0.2 and Java 17.0.3, both downloaded from https://adoptium.net/.

```java
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.VarHandle;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

  private static final VarHandle MODIFIERS;

  static {
    try {
      var lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(Field.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
      MODIFIERS = lookup.findVarHandle(Field.class, "modifiers", int.class);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var emptyElementDataField = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA");
    // make field non-final
    MODIFIERS.set(emptyElementDataField, emptyElementDataField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    
    // set field to new value
    emptyElementDataField.setAccessible(true);
    emptyElementDataField.set(null, new Object[] {"Hello", "World!"});

    var list = new ArrayList<>(0);

    // println uses toString(), and ArrayList.toString() indirectly relies on 'size'
    var sizeField = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("size");
    sizeField.setAccessible(true);
    sizeField.set(list, 2); // the new "empty element data" has a length of 2

    System.out.println(list);
  }
}
```

Run the code with:

```
javac Main.java
java --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED Main
```

<sup>**Note:** I tried to use the "single source file" feature, but that resulted in a `ConcurrentModificationException`. As pointed out in the comments, this is likely due to some JIT optimization (e.g., the static final field has been inlined, because the JVM does not expect such a field to be able to change).</sup>

Output:

```
[Hello, World!]
```

#### Java 18+

Unfortunately, the above results in the following exception on Java 18.0.1 (downloaded from https://adoptium.net/):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.VarForm.getMemberName(VarForm.java:114)
        at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Where line 23 is:

```
MODIFIERS.set(emptyElementDataField, emptyElementDataField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
```

Comment: This approach may break at any time so best not to rely on it. In general, nobody should expect to be able to change a static final field. The long standing recommendation for mocking and other testing tools is to use an agent and drop the final modifier of fields that you want to mock.

Comment: So... as a non Java developer: "How does one 'Extend the filter to all fields' of the classes listed in this super popular answer?". How and where? What should I do with the provided list of classes to get to the promised land? I was just handed a legacy library where I was supposed to change a string and build a new jar file. All the tests seems to fail because of this issue. "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers"

Comment: @MrMambo007 My answer is only meant to show that `VarHandle` can, at least for the moment, be used in place of reflection to access "forbidden" internals. How one integrates this into their application is highly dependent on the application. I can only suggest you follow the stack trace to where your library uses reflection and see if you can switch over to `VarHandle` with minimal disruption to the rest of the code. Assuming there's little to no code duplication and adequate abstraction the change shouldn't be too hard. If you need more specific help consider asking a new question.

Comment: There seems to be general pattern of the invoke package not performing the same checks as reflect, e.g. you can instantiate new enum constants without a problem. By the way, as long as your code belongs to the unnamed module, you can even eliminate the warning programmatically via inserting `Module java_base = Field.class.getModule(), unnamed = FieldHelper.class.getModule(); java_base.addOpens("java.lang.reflect", unnamed); java_base.addOpens("java.util", unnamed);` at the beginning of `FieldHelper`’s initializer.

Comment: @Holger Looks like the `java.lang.invoke` workaround has been patched in Java 18. It now seems to fail with an `UnsupportedOperationException` (see answer).

Comment: "The developers of Java obviously don't want you to be able to make fields non-final at run-time" - this is plain wrong. If you don't want to have a field `final` at runtime, use a java agent and remove the `final` modifier from the field.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I struggle to see how that's wrong, considering all the restrictions they're adding to the reflection/invoke API. Instrumentation works differently, if I'm not mistaken. You're essentially modifying the byte-code and loading a "different" class, no?

Comment: Right. This is the only supported way. As I have shown before, [you can't even reliably change `static final` fields on Java 8](https://gist.github.com/DasBrain/ca16053f8e073c8a883bee66302c2fee).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Is changing a field from `final` to non-`final` actually supported by the Instrumentation API? The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) says: "_Instrumentation is the addition of byte-codes to methods for the purpose of gathering data to be utilized by tools. Since the changes are purely additive, these tools do not modify application state or behavior_".

Comment: When we consider load-time instrumentation, it’s not different to modifying the class files even before starting the JVM, so the [Binary Compatibility constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9-200) apply. Unless the `final` field also was a compile-time constant, it may work through instrumentation.

Comment: @Holger Right, that makes sense. But what I'm trying to determine is if I should change the wording of my answer. Does instrumentation _support_ making a field non-final, or does it merely not fail when you make a field non-final (not the same thing). Your use of the word "may", and the wording of the Javadoc, makes me think it is not supported, but won't cause an error if you try. In which case, saying the Java developers don't want you to be able to change a field to be non-final at run-time seems correct to me. But if it _is_ supported, I'd like to add that as an option in my answer.

Comment: @Slaw ["In the retransform and redefine cases, the transformer must support the redefinition semantics: if a class that the transformer changed during initial definition is later retransformed or redefined, the transformer must insure that the second class output class file is a legal redefinition of the first output class file. "](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html), also see Instumentation.retransformClasses, which points at the JVMTI spec.

Comment: I’d phrase it like this: “*You can not remove the `final` modifier through Reflection; the only way to remove it, is by actually changing the class*”. It doesn’t matter whether you change the persistent class files after compilation or change them on-the-fly through Instrumentation; in either case, you’re actually changing the class, rather than patching some Reflection artifacts. I dug a bit in the JDK 18 code and the interesting point is, even if changing the modifiers field that way worked, it would have no impact on the ability to modify the field.

Comment: I suppose, when you use the single-source-file feature, the `ArrayList` has been used so much already (when compiling your example on-the-fly), that the `static final` field access has been optimized by the JIT, so the reflection hack has no effect on this field while the change of the `size` field is within specification (kind of), so it’s still done. Having a size of two but an array of length zero (the already inlined original reference) is an indicator for a concurrent modification. Consistently, when you use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));` you get `[null, null]`.

Comment: This helped, modifiers needs to be accessed from MethodHandles privatelookup

Comment: @Abhinavmanthri Are you saying `privateLookupIn` works in Java 18 or newer? Because the workaround example in my answer uses `privateLookupIn` already.

Comment: @Slaw, i mean to say your workaround really worked for me :)

Answer (score 16):

I found a way and it worked on JDK 8, 11, 17.

```java
Method getDeclaredFields0 = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDeclaredFields0", boolean.class);
getDeclaredFields0.setAccessible(true);
Field[] fields = (Field[]) getDeclaredFields0.invoke(Field.class, false);
Field modifiers = null;
for (Field each : fields) {
    if ("modifiers".equals(each.getName())) {
        modifiers = each;
        break;
    }
}
assertNotNull(modifiers);
```

Don't forget to set the following args when using JDK 11 or higher:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Nice, this indeed works with JDK17!
This allows us to upgrade a project to JDK17, and workaround a bug - until our fix is officially integrated into the JDK.

Comment: Stops working with JDK 18. The code of this answer still works in that you get a `Field` instance for the `modifiers` field that you can manipulate, but it won’t give you write access to non-modifiable final fields.

Answer (score 12):

You can't. This was a change done on purpose.

For example, you could use `PowerMock` and it's `@PrepareForTest` - under the hood it uses [javassist](http://www.javassist.org/) (bytecode manipulation) if you want to use that for testing purposes. This is exactly what that bug in the comments suggests to do.

In other words, since `java-12` - there is no way to access that via vanilla java.

Answer (score 9):

[This](https://github.com/Arnuh/EchoPet/commit/52befe50de976e952be09c068c5a41fa1947f1b3) works in JDK 17.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import sun.misc.Unsafe;

/**
 * @author Arnah
 * @since Feb 21, 2021
 **/
public class FieldUtil{

    private static Unsafe unsafe;

    static{
        try{
            final Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
            unsafe = (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object value) throws Exception{
        Object fieldBase = unsafe.staticFieldBase(field);
        long fieldOffset = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(field);

        unsafe.putObject(fieldBase, fieldOffset, value);
    }
}
```

```
public class YourClass{
    public static final int MAX_ITEM_ROWS = 35_000;
}

FieldUtil.setFinalStatic(YourClass.class.getDeclaredField("MAX_ITEM_ROWS"), 1);
```

Comment: 1) `public static final int MAX_ITEM_ROWS = 35_000;` is a compile-time constant. At each place where `MAX_ITEM_ROWS` is read, the constant value `35_000` is already inserted at compile-time. 2) Of course, you won’t notice when your example is trying to set the field’s value to `35_000`, the same value it already has. Of course, when “no change” is considered a success, it will look like a success everywhere. 3) if you were able to read the value you’ve written, you’d notice that this code failed badly. You are setting an *object reference* to an *int* variable. Only `Unsafe` makes it possible…

Comment: I get this on Java 17.0.5+9-LTS-191
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldBase0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldBase(Unsafe.java:1128)
        at jdk.unsupported/sun.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldBase(Unsafe.java:707)
        at FieldUtil.setFinalStatic(Example.java:24) Even with `--add-opens`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible without `java.misc.Unsafe` on Java 21 with the following Code and JVM parameters:

JVM-Parameters:

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.access=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Java-Code

```java
public class HiddenFieldsRevealed {

    private static final Object greeting = "Hello world";

    public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {

        Field myStaticFinalField = HiddenFieldsRevealed.class.getDeclaredField("greeting");
        myStaticFinalField.setAccessible(true);

        removeFinalness(myStaticFinalField);

        //Logic taken from java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.unreflectSetter(Field)
        
        //.unreflectSetter(Field) 
        //=> .unreflectField(Field, false)
        //=> lookup.getDirectFieldNoSecurityManager(memberName.getReferenceKind(), f.getDeclaringClass(), memberName);
        //=> .getDirectFieldCommon(refKind, referenceClass, memberName, false)
        
        Class<?> memberNameClass = Class.forName("java.lang.invoke.MemberName");
        
        Constructor<?> memberNameConstructor = memberNameClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Field.class, boolean.class);
        memberNameConstructor.setAccessible(true);

        Object memberNameInstanceForField = memberNameConstructor.newInstance(myStaticFinalField, true);
        
        Field memberNameFlagsField = memberNameClass.getDeclaredField("flags");
        
        memberNameFlagsField.setAccessible(true);
        
        //Manipulate flags to remove hints to it being final
        memberNameFlagsField.setInt(memberNameInstanceForField, (int)memberNameFlagsField.getInt(memberNameInstanceForField) & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        
        Method getReferenceKindMethod = memberNameClass.getDeclaredMethod("getReferenceKind");
        
        getReferenceKindMethod.setAccessible(true);
        
        byte getReferenceKind = (byte)getReferenceKindMethod.invoke(memberNameInstanceForField);

        MethodHandles.Lookup mh = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(HiddenFieldsRevealed.class, MethodHandles.lookup());

        Method getDirectFieldCommonMethod = mh.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getDirectFieldCommon", byte.class, Class.class, memberNameClass, boolean.class);
        
        getDirectFieldCommonMethod.setAccessible(true);
        
        //Invoke last method to obtain the method handle

        MethodHandle o = (MethodHandle) getDirectFieldCommonMethod.invoke(mh, getReferenceKind, myStaticFinalField.getDeclaringClass(), memberNameInstanceForField, false);
        
        o.invoke("ModifiedValue");

        System.out.println(greeting);

    }

    public static void removeFinalness(Field field) throws Throwable {
        Method[] classMethods = Class.class.getDeclaredMethods();

        Method declaredFieldMethod = Arrays.stream(classMethods).filter(x -> Objects.equals(x.getName(), "getDeclaredFields0")).findAny().orElseThrow();

        declaredFieldMethod.setAccessible(true);

        Field[] declaredFieldsOfField = (Field[]) declaredFieldMethod.invoke(Field.class, false);

        Field modifiersField = Arrays.stream(declaredFieldsOfField).filter(x -> Objects.equals(x.getName(), "modifiers")).findAny().orElseThrow();

        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);

        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    }
}
```

As of Java 21 this works because of the direct call to `getDirectFieldCommon(...)` that we can fool by modifying the flags on `MemberName` instance for a field.

Considering that `Unsafe.getStaticFieldOffset(...)` is deprecated and this workaround is prone to break, I hope that there will be always a way in the future to modify static final fields at runtime because there are some nasty dependencies that are easier to deal with this way than to have the whole ordeal of writing something that instruments the class or to patch the library on compile with a build system just to remove a `final` where it should not have been in the first place.