# Field usr_paths in ClassLoader not found

Tags: java, java-12

I'm following a tutorial, which at some point use this code.

`ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths")`.

Why it throws exception

`java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: usr_paths`

Classloader class decompiled definition shows that is has.

`private static String usr_paths[];`

I'm using:
java 12.0.1 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Related: [Get declared fields of java.lang.reflect.Fields in jdk12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039341/get-declared-fields-of-java-lang-reflect-fields-in-jdk12). The `ClassLoader` class is filtered from core reflection, same as `Field`. You can use a similar solution as shown in the the Q&A I linked, but note that they're filtering certain classes for a reason.

Comment: A tutorial that involves hacking a private member of a JDK class doesn't sound like a good thing. Which tutorial is this?