# Change value in a TextField inside a TreeTableCell in OpenJFX

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

While accessing the field using getDeclaredField("textField") no longer works from Java12 I am looking for a better way to update the text inside a TreeTableView.

I was thinking of a **TextFieldTreeTableCell**, would that work? 
How can be instantiated a TextFieldTreeTableCell from a TreeTableCell?
Will be this a better practice to update the text into a TreeTableView?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTreeTableCell.html

```
Field field = cell.getClass().getDeclaredField("textField");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object obj = field.get(cell);

                if (obj instanceof TextField) {
                    TextField textField = (TextField) obj;
                    textField.clear();
                    textField.setText(text);
```

Comment: what do you mean? [mcve] please ..

Comment: you don't need reflective access, either lookup or listen to the cell's graphic property

Comment: .. the real question is _why_ do you want that? smells a bit like a x-y-problem :)

Comment: @kleopatra when I have upgraded application JDK from Java8 to Java13 and this no longer work. Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039341/get-declared-fields-of-java-lang-reflect-fields-in-jdk12

Comment: Why would you have code like this in the first place? If you want the text to change, just change the appropriate value in the model.

Comment: @James_D, this is exactly what I will try to avoid. I have tried for now a cell.SetGraphic(textField) where I have created a new textField. but doesn't work

Comment: But why are you trying to manipulate the cell at all? Just change the data in the model.

Comment: .commitEdit(textField.getText()));

Comment: @James_D will it be possible under any circumstances to do it?

Comment: [mcve] please, demonstrating what _exactly_ you want to achieve, how it did work before and doesn't anymore (mind the __M__ and stick to java naming conventions!).