# Why does java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.class.getDeclaredFields() not return any field anymore?

Tags: java, reflection

The class `java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject` has multiple private fields, for example `override` which is present both in JDK 11 ([source](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u/file/6aa55a45ff6f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.java#l493)) and JDK 14 ([source](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk14u/file/3034d548d15c/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.java#l502)).

However, only for JDK 11 `Class.getDeclaredFields()` and `getDeclaredField(String)` return the fields, for JDK 14 (and possibly even since JDK 12) no field is returned.

```
import java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class AccessibleObjectTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (Field f : AccessibleObject.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println(f);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this?

Is there some special casing for this class because by using `sun.misc.Unsafe` it would otherwise easily be possible to circumvent reflective access checks ([example](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/ceae88bd6667f4263bbe02e6b3710b8a683906a2/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/reflect/UnsafeReflectionAccessor.java#L54))?

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210522

Comment: Thanks, that is actually the answer to this question, mind adding this as answer?

Comment: Someone else did already write [a really comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043252/2711488).