# 'Schema-validation: missing table' with custom SchemaFilterProvider after upgrading to Spring Boot 3 (Hibernate 6)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-6.x, spring-boot-3

When upgrading to Spring Boot 3 and Hibernate 6, it seems like property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.schema_filter_provider` doesn't work properly. I have a custom implementation of SchemaFilterProvider that excludes `my_table` from validation, and I set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.schema_filter_provider` property to use it. I get this error:
`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [my_table]`

After debugging it, I found that `DefaultSchemaFilter.INSTANCE` is in use, and the above property is not being considered:

Validation is done here:

```
    protected void validateTables(
            Metadata metadata,
            DatabaseInformation databaseInformation,
            ExecutionOptions options,
            ContributableMatcher contributableInclusionFilter,
            Dialect dialect, Namespace namespace) {

        final NameSpaceTablesInformation tables = databaseInformation.getTablesInformation( namespace );
        for ( Table table : namespace.getTables() ) {
            if ( options.getSchemaFilter().includeTable( table )
                    && table.isPhysicalTable()
                    && contributableInclusionFilter.matches( table ) ) {
                validateTable(
                        table,
                        tables.getTableInformation( table ),
                        metadata,
                        options,
                        dialect
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

and `options` is built here:

```
    public static ExecutionOptions buildExecutionOptions(
            final Map<String,Object> configurationValues,
            final ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler) {
        return buildExecutionOptions(
                configurationValues,
                DefaultSchemaFilter.INSTANCE,
                exceptionHandler
        );
    }
```

Meaning `DefaultSchemaFilter.INSTANCE` will always be in use.

There's an open bug to Hibernate with no response:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HBX-2476

How should I exclude `my_table` from validation?

Answer (score 0):

It is almost a year now since https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HBX-2476 was opened and it is still not resolved.
Going to share a **nasty workaround** that works at least for me, until the bug is fixed.

### A temporary workaround

Using reflection, set the value of the (static final) `DefaultSchemaFilter.INSTANCE` to reference an instance of the custom `SchemaFilter` that worked with earlier Hibernate versions. This way when Hibernate is going to use the "hard coded" `DefaultSchemaFilter.INSTANCE` as filter, it is actually going to use our custom filter implementation. Note that the custom implementation `extends DefaultSchemaFilter`.

For example, assume we have this custom implementation that skips validation of PostgreSQL temp tables:

```
public class CustomSchemaFilter extends DefaultSchemaFilter {

    public static final CustomSchemaFilter INSTANCE = new CustomSchemaFilter();

    @Override
    public boolean includeTable( Table table ) {
        return !"pg_temp".equals(table.getSchema());
    }
}
```

We need to set `DefaultSchemaFilter.INSTANCE = CustomSchemaFilter.INSTANCE`.

The exact implementation of the reflection code that achieves this depends on Java version. For Java 17, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043252/9061851, I used this:

```
try {
    Field defaultSchemaFilterInstanceField = DefaultSchemaFilter.class.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE");
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(Field.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
    VarHandle modifiers = lookup.findVarHandle(Field.class, "modifiers", int.class);
    modifiers.set(defaultSchemaFilterInstanceField, defaultSchemaFilterInstanceField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    defaultSchemaFilterInstanceField.setAccessible(true);
    defaultSchemaFilterInstanceField.set(null, CustomSchemaFilter.INSTANCE);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

However this requires adding `--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED` to the JVM run parameters.

This piece of code should be called before Hibernate runs its validations. The simplest option is to call it from `main()` before loading Spring Boot.
**Reminder: this is just a temporary workaround.**