# How can you assign a mock to a private static field in Java 17?

Tags: java, testing, powermock

Suppose I need to assert on the behavior of an object stored in a `private static final` field (and I can't change the modifiers because, for example, it's a write-only class or generated code)

```java
public class SomeClass {
    private static final HardCodedDependency hardCodedDependency = HardCodedDependency.getInstance();
    
    public void doSomething() {
        // I need to make sure someMethod() is invoked on HardCodedDependency on every doSomething() invocation
        hardCodedDependency.someMethod();
    }
}
```

I need to instantiate `SomeClass` and then reassign a mock to `constantField`

I discovered there are some [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56039341/23539854) starting from at least JDK17 (my JDK's version). I can no longer pull this off:

```java
    @SneakyThrows
    private void makeNonFinal(Field field) {
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers"); // throws
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    }
```

Apparently, you'd need to run your code with CLI arguments (which I don't want to do)

```
java --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED Main
```

or you PowerMock

Unfortunately, I didn't find code samples showing that

Can you give me an example of how I can achieve my goal with PowerMock?

Comment: You forgot option 3: refactor the code, make it testable.

Comment: @Turing85 it's Lombok's `@Slf4j` logger, there's nothing I can do. Jacoco wants me to test my `if (..) log.*` as well so I'm trying to find a *good* way to do it. It's *not* asserting on sout or regex of the log message. "Out" may change, message format may change

Comment: Why do you want to mock the logger? --- Of course you can do something: do not use `@Slf4j`. If we are using spring/quarkus/... we can write a custom injection rule to make the logger injectable.

Comment: @Turing85 I don't want to inject loggers in my classes. Their constructors already take about three args each. I don't want to bloat arg lists

Comment: This is a no-argument. The class clearly has a dependency on the logger. Whether the logger is injected or defined on a static field is irrelevant; the injection, however, is more explicit and easier to test. --- You still haven't said why you want to mock the logger, i.e. what you want to test with that mock.

Comment: @Turing85 check my previous comment please. I added a note about Jacoco

Comment: You are on a trip down a rabbit hole, and it will not end good. Not everything is testworthy. I recommend reading an article about code coverage and its meaning, e.g  [this one from `camgemini.github.io`](https://capgemini.github.io/testing/What-Is-Code-Coverage-and-Why-It-Should-Not-Lead-Development/). If this log is testworthy (e.g. because it is mission-critical), I would recommend injecting the logger.

Comment: @Turing85 what about TDD? Suppose I figure at some point it would be nice to insert some `log.debug()` here and there. Kent Beck forbids you to write any production code before you write a failing test. From TDD's standpoint, everything is "mission critical" and has to be covered. But oh my, injecting loggers... It doesn't feel right. Any class would have to have one extra dependency (not related to its responsibility) right from the start

Comment: And then you may have an event publisher which is also common. So it makes two dependencies before you begin to include any dependencies specific to the class. Bob Martin said three args is too many for a function. I believe it includes constructors