# Force kill a class made by a third party within a task

Tags: javafx

Assuming a service that loads a third-party class and this class has an infinite loop, in this simplified example "a virus that consumes cpu".

How to forcefully terminate the service and kill the execution of this class?

Reinforcing that it is a class made by a third party and the main software loads it, of course the structure involves the implementation of an interface, but in this example it excludes it to make the problem more visible.
Previously in Thread there was the stop() method, in JavaFX there is a cancellation of the service, but although it stops, the class called from it continues running

With Debug or monitoring program you can observe that even after cancel() the virus class continues to run.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
 
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button; 
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExecutorTask extends Application {
    
    Button startButton =null;
    Button endButton =null;
     
    boolean in_process = false;
    
    Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();    
    TaskView task = null;
    
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        startButton = new Button("Start Task  ");
        endButton   = new Button("Force Kill Class");
        
        VBox root = new VBox(startButton,endButton);
     
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        startButton.setOnAction(event -> {            
           if(in_process == true) {
               return;
           }
           
           task = new TaskView();
           executor.execute(task);  
        });
         
        endButton.setOnAction(event -> {
           task.virus = null; 
           task.cancel();          
           task = null;            
        });
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class TaskView extends Task<Void> {
        
        Virus virus = null;
 
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {               
            in_process = true;
            try {
               
               Class clazz = Class.forName("Virus");
               
               Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
                                
               constructor.setAccessible(true);
               
               virus = (Virus)constructor.newInstance();
               virus.calc();
               
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            in_process = false;
            return null;
        } 
    }
}




// This class illustrates a class made by third parties and has the 
// behavior of a virus, whose objective is to leave the CPU compromised
class Virus {
                
        public Virus() {             
        }
        
        public void calc() {
           
           long count = 0;
           
           while(true) {
              count++;
              Thread.yield();
           }
           
        }
}
```

Comment: [`Process::destroyForcibly`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#destroyForcibly())?

Comment: No, Killing the process kills the main application.
The intention is to kill only the instantiated third class

Comment: You don't kill classes, you terminate threads that are executing.  Potential duplicate: [Is there a good way to forcefully stop a Java thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241822/is-there-a-good-way-to-forcefully-stop-a-java-thread).  None of the answers there you are likely to like.  To cleanly shutdown a thread, the code on which the thread is executing needs to be written to allow that (for instance see the [Task javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) section on cancellation), which might not be the case for third party code.

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder` to create a `Process` that can be destroyed. See also [_How do I create a Java sandbox?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1715036/230513)